# Check for nullptr and valid index in the same if statement

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement

Here is an oversimplified version of a code I am working on. I want to check if an index is in valid bounds and if in an array at the given index there's an object in one if statement.

```
int main(){
  int* anArray[5]; // in the code there's either an object here or a nullptr
  int anIndex = 2; // something that I get from the depths of my code

  // int* <- typename not allowed
  // elem <- indentifier is undefined
  if(anIndex < 5 && int* elem = anArray[anIndex]){
    // use elem here
  }
return 0;
}
```

I can use two if-statements to check the index and then check for the object, but after a while there are if statements everywhere, and I'd like to avoid that. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The problem is not with the indexing, the problem is that if I check for something **and** then I want to get a pointer I get the errors mentioned above the if-statement

Comment: Is there a default value you can use?  Do you even get values of `anIndex >= 5`?  Why?  Can that be changed to just not happen instead?  What does it mean when `anArray[anIndex] == NULL`?  Is there some value you could give instead that makes sense?  As is, there's too little context to really know the answer to this.

Comment: The problem is that you are allowing `anArray` to be a `nullptr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [Conditional (or Ternary) Operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/) (`?`). Evaluate if the index is in bouds, in the condition expression of the operator. If the expression is evaluated to `true`, then you can access to the array directly. The expression for the `false` case is `nullptr`:

```
int* anArray[5];
int anIndex = 2;

if ( int* elem = anIndex >= 0 && anIndex < 5 ? anArray[anIndex] : nullptr ){
    // use elem here
}
```

Comment: @JameyD: This does check if `anArray` contains a `nullptr`, since `if` considers `nullptr` as `false`. However it doesn't check of `anArray` is `nullptr`.

Comment: @Guvante Here anArray is an array and not a pointer, so it can't be NULL

Comment: @GuyGreer: "in the code there's either an object here or a nullptr" meaning that it looks like he oversimplified.

Comment: @Guvante It's an array of pointers, so I assumed he meant that the elements might be NULL and he just wants to check those.

Comment: @Guvante It is `int* anArray[5]` and not `int **anArray`

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this;

```
if(anIndex < 5 && anArray[anIndex]){
    int* elem = anArray[anIndex]
}
```

And if you need to you might want to check if anIndex is >= 0 too.

Comment: This is C++ question so you can declare variable in `if`, though not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
int anIndex = 2; // something that i get from the depths of my code

if(anIndex < 5 && int* elem = anArray[anIndex]){
   // use elem here
}
```

Here, in theory, anIndex could be nagative, so an extra check is needed:

```
int *elem = NULL;
if(anIndex >= 0 && anIndex < 5 && (elem = anArray[anIndex])){
  // use elem here
  // will only get here if elem is not NULL
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would invert this to exit when conditions aren't met so that as more conditions get added it is easier to follow:

```
int main(){
  int* anArray[5]; // in the code there's either an object here or a nullptr
  int anIndex = 2; // something that I get from the depths of my code

  // anIndex may change here

  if (anIndex < 0) // added from comments about it
  {
      return 0;
  }

  if (anIndex >= 5)
  {
      return 0;
  }

  int* elem = anArray[anIndex]);

  if (!elem)
  {
      return 0;
  }

    // use elem here

   return 0;
}
```

Think about how easy this would be when stepping through the debugger to figure out your edge cases.